# CakePHP keeping business logic out of views

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

My Controller sets a variable named `$price`, in view I need to display it, if it is a positive number it shows the class `positive-value` but `negative-value`. Here is my actually way:

```
<p class="<?php echo $price >= 0 ? 'positive-value' : 'negative-value'; ?>">
<?php echo $price ?>
</p>
```

Is that a good practice or should I to put this on model?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this.  Class name is display logic.  Would be far worse to have your model setting class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a models concern whether something is being displayed in green or in blue, what a model cares about is the data itself.

In case the price belongs to a model, then `$price >= 0` is a facet of that model, and so one might argue that the model should check that internally an expose the price status (negative or positive) which could then be checked in the view, something like

```
<p class="<?php echo $modelData['price_status'] === TheModel.POSITIVE_PRICE ? 'positive-value' : 'negative-value'; ?>">
```

Basically what I'm trying to say is that it's perfectly fine for a view to contain some logic, as long as it's for presentation purposes.